# How to launch PHP file from Javascript without window.open

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

I'm using Javascript and I need to call a PHP file to execute some stuff, but I'd like not to use `window.open("filename.php");` because it usually opens a new tab or new window.

Sometime a PHP file need a few seconds to finish its job and I don't like to see an open tab or open window while it's working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ajax or dynamically create iframe.

If you use extjs library - [here](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/22/make-an-ajax-call-with-the-extjs-framework.html) is example ajax request

Comment: thanks which is the different between Ext.Ajax.request and the example u post Ext.data.Connection?

Comment: Ext.data - is higher level than Ext.Ajax
For launching php file offcourse is simpler use Ext.Ajax.

Answer (score 6):

AJAX is the solution, and with jQuery it's so simple.

Just add this line on your head section (to include jquery):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "yourPage.php"
    }).done(function( data) {
      alert( "Request is done" );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm using ExtJs Framework. Do u think that i could use parts of both Frameworks in the same App? How could i handle object between them?

Comment: I'm sure that both can work together, but I really don't know ExtJs so  I can't tell. But, use ExtJS Ajax method is as simple as jQuery one. Just have a look to the documentation here : [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax)

Answer (score 2):

Use Ajax! Here's a solution using JavaScript's jQuery library:

```
$.post('your_file.php', {parameter : some_value}, function(response){
  // now you can use `response` came from your_file.php after execution
});
```

[`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) are shorthand methods for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of jQuery.

or simply use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/),

```
('#test_div').load('your_file.php'); //load data from server into `#test_div`
```

will do job, if you want to just execute something on server-side.